# How to bold all letters of volume number?

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, bold

I used `h-physrev` for my bibliography, but the volume numbers of articles are not bold all letters, they are bold only for the first letters, for example

> S. Ono and Y. Ando, Phys. Rev. B **6**7, 104512 (2003).

Could you tell me how to make bold all letters of volume field?

---

Here's an MWE that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{Ono2003, 
  author  = "S. Ono and Y. Ando", 
  title   = "Evolution of the resistivity anisotropy", 
  journal = "Phys. Rev. B",
  year    = "2003",
  volume  = "67", 
  pages   = "104512" 
} 

@article{Sakai2013, 
  author  ="S. Sakai and S. Blanc and M. Civelli and Y. Gallais", 
  title   = "Raman-Scattering Measurements", 
  journal = "Phys. Rev. Lett.", 
  year    = "2013", 
  volume  = "111", 
  pages  = "107001--107005" 
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{cite} 
\begin{document} 
This is one of my references. \cite{Ono2003} 
It is bold only for the first digit of the volume number. 
And here is another one. \cite{Sakai2013} 
\bibliographystyle{h-physrev} 
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key piece of information is that you're using the `memoir` document class.

Inside the bibliography style file you employ, `h-physrev.bst`, lurks the command `\bf`, a plain-TeX macro which is seriously deprecated under LaTeX. Many LaTeX document classes -- including the "standard" classes `article`, `report` and `book` -- have redefined `\bf` to accommodate those users who either need to compile legacy document or who can't seem to shake the habit of using `\bf` when they should be using either `\textbf{...}` or `{\bfseries ...}`. Unfortunately, `\bf` is also still in use in many auxiliary files, such as BibTeX style files, especially if they haven't been updated in many years to conform to current LaTeX best practice.

However, the `memoir` document class does not appear to be so accommodating: when I run your MWE, I get the following message:

> Class memoir Error: Font command \bf is not supported.

You *could* edit the file `h-physrev.bst` and replace `\bf` with `\bfseries`. However, a simpler solution would consist of adding the instruction

```
\renewcommand\bf\bfseries
```

to the preamble of your document. You're not using `\bf` anywhere else in your document, right?! :-)

With this change, your MWE's bibliography will look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{memoir} 
\renewcommand\bf\bfseries  % this is new
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{Ono2003, 
  author  = "S. Ono and Y. Ando", 
  title   = "Evolution of the resistivity anisotropy", 
  journal = "Phys. Rev. B",
  year    = "2003",
  volume  = "67", 
  pages   = "104512" 
} 
@article{Sakai2013, 
  author  ="S. Sakai and S. Blanc and M. Civelli and Y. Gallais", 
  title   = "Raman-Scattering Measurements", 
  journal = "Phys. Rev. Lett.", 
  year    = "2013", 
  volume  = "111", 
  pages  = "107001--107005" 
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{cite} 
\begin{document} 
This is one of my references. \cite{Ono2003} 
It is bold only for the first digit of the volume number. And here is another one. \cite{Sakai2013} 
\bibliographystyle{h-physrev} 
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a follow-up comment by the OP (which has been deleted in the meantime): The OP indicated that he/she had also changed `\bf` to `\textbf` in the bibliography style file. This modification explains why he/she didn't get an outright error message but, instead, the outcome that only the first digit of the volume number was typeset in boldface. The macro `\textbf` expects an argument delimited with curly braces. If no braces are provided, the macro applies only to the very next token. This is why it's important to use `\bfseries`, which acts as a switch, rather than `\textbf` to fix the problem at hand.